# How to make from src directory in build directory?

Tags: linux, build, makefile

My question is short and simple. I have my source directory mySrcDir, where my `Makefile` is also located and I want to compile it into my build directory myBuildDir.

How do I `make` the content of my `/some/path/mySrcDir` into `/another/path/myBuildDir`?

P.S: OS Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: That depends **entirely** on your makefile. The default built-in make rules don't support doing that directly.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Can you show us the part of this problem you already know how to do (e.g. building targets in `mySrcDir`)?

Comment: 1) I create myBuildDir 2) I call ../mySrcDir/configure 3) I call make 4) I call sudo make install. So far so good. Now I want to recompile a subdirectory under mySrcDir (mySrcDir/mySubSrcDir) with a modified Makefile. I can call make & sudo make install in mySubSrcDir, but this is not the elegant way I think. That's why I want to compile it in myBuildDir and then install..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) In your build directory call this :

```
make -f /some/path/mySrcDir/your-makefile
```

The -f option is to specify the file you're trying to 'make'.

2) If the Makefile was generated by GNU autotools you can try this :

```
./configure --prefix=/another/path/myBuildDir
```

and then `make`

Comment: I configured and made my whole source directory into my build directory. Now I want to recompile a subdirectory with custom options. I thought, I can create a "sub-build" directory somewhere and call `make` inside it for the subdirectory in my source folder.

Comment: Try this : `make -C /another/path/myBuildDir`

Comment: When I call the make command inside the src directory, where the Makefile is also located, it says: 
make: Entering directory `/another/path/myBuildDir`
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/another/path/myBuildDir`

Comment: Call it from your build directory  : make -C /some/path/mySrcDir . Let me know if this is working

Comment: Apparentl it is the same calling it inside the source directory. It started compiling into source directory

Comment: I made a mistake I wanted to say :   make -f /some/path/mySrcDir/your-makefile. ( Call it from your build directory ) The f option is to specify the file you're trying to make.

Comment: Make an answer out of this comment and I will acecpt it.. I think it worked fine! Now testing it..

Comment: also another question. How do I install it? Executing sudo make install in the build folder doesn't work. There is no makefile in the folder. again with the -f option?

Comment: I called sudo make install -f mySrcDir/Makefile inside the buildDir but it gave me an error during installing. It couldn't find a .moc file. I think it is not that easy.. I am giving up :)